# Effect changes to JavaScript code are influential anywhere in terms of application performance?

Tags: javascript

I want to ask if I change a few lines of JavaScript function code, rename the function, change position to the last of the file, or make another change. To which parts of the changes do I make to the application I made the change?

For example, I changed the JavaScript code on 1 file to display the main page. Whether the change affects other pages in terms of application performance or other page access speeds (in this case, let's say the user has no interruption in internet speed)?

I am very grateful for every comment you give.

Comment: If the changes don't really change the semantics or execution of the code, then there would be no performance impact. Even then, unless the changes introduce *major* shift in how things work (e.g., different computation complexity), then the changes in speed would be negligable. And If you change things in one place that is not at all related to another (e.g., different pages with different JS files imported), then there is no difference to the speed.

Comment: @VLAZ It means that changes in 1 file do not affect other files although changing semantic or code execution of the program?

Comment: If the two files are unrelated, then no - there is no way the two would be influenced. But if fileA.js uses fileB.js and you change fileB, that can affect fileA. Changing the code semantics *could* have an effect depending on what the change is. It's also possible that the change is negligable. Renames do not change semantics, for example. Changing from `while(i--)` to `while(--i)` does change the semantics and ends up looping one less times but that's overall still `O(n)`. Moreover, if the time to execute each iteration is, say, 1ms, then you're not saving that much time.

Comment: on the frontend you use usually frameworks with babel and webpack that optimize your code at the end when you want to deploy it

Comment: @VLAZ OK, thank you very much, it was very helpful. Keep yourself safe in this Covid-19 pandemic.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by adding tests to your code.

- **Component/E2E tests** - This will help you check a single page while the whole app is running. (example: [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/))
- **Visual Regression Testing** - This is how you can compare snapshots of your application. (example: [BackstopJS](https://garris.github.io/BackstopJS/))

I keep this answer vague because your tools may change regarding your code-base.
I suggest you start by googling and finding tools that fit your project.